# Why isn't jQuery slide direction left working on show/hide?

Tags: jquery, slider, show-hide

Can't figure it out why I cant apply 'slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000 to hide/show in this case. If the slider is without 'slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000 it works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.custom-header__background>li:gt(0)').hide(); 
     setInterval(function() {
        $('.custom-header__background > li:first')
          .hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000)
          .next()
          .show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000)
          .end()
          .appendTo('.custom-header__background');
      }, 2000);
   });
```

Comment: `"slide"` is not a valid argument to [jquery hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) method.  Are you using an additional plugin?  Looks like it might be [jquery-ui](https://api.jqueryui.com/hide/)

Comment: No I am not using a plugin

Comment: *jquery's* hide does not have that format, jquery-ui's does and seems to work "ok-ish" when including jquery-ui:  https://jsfiddle.net/sdt59pec/  as you say you're not using jquery-ui, can you provide a link to where/why you think `.hide("slide"...` would work?  ie where did you get this from?